# Why is addClass not recognised as a function in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add a class to a bunch of links whose suffix ends in `.pdf` as follows:

```
var pdfs = jQuery("a[href$='.pdf']"); //Choosing .pdf links
pdfs.each(addClass("pdf")); // Adding the class
```

This doesn't work, however, as the browser console prints this error when I try  to reload the HTML file calling the .js file:

> ReferenceError: addClass is not defined

Why is this happening?

Comment: It should be `pdfs.addClass("pdf")` _Why is this happening?_ because You have not defined the function `addClass()`

Comment: It's because you're calling `addClass()` as if it were an externally defined function, not as though it's part of a jQuery object. Note that you don't even need the `each()` here, just `$("a[href$='.pdf']").addClass('pdf');` will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery allows you to perform it's API methods not only on single elements, but also on collections of elements (which is one of the nice advantages over the native DOM API).

The easiest way to achieve your goal is to capitalize on that:

```
var pdfs = jQuery("a[href$='.pdf']"); //Choosing .pdf links
pdfs.addClass("pdf"); // Adding the class
```

jQuery `$.each()` function is for those cases where you want to do something with each element in the collection that is not available as an API method in jQuery. It expects you pass it a function that gets passed the current element in each iteration as `this`:

```
var pdfs = jQuery("a[href$='.pdf']"); //Choosing .pdf links
pdfs.each(function() { console.log(this.href); }) // perform something jQuery doesn't offer as an API method
```

If you insist on using `$.each()`, the code is this:

```
var pdfs = jQuery("a[href$='.pdf']"); //Choosing .pdf links
pdfs.each(function() { $(this).addClass("pdf"); }); // Adding the class
```

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/addClass/

After choosing the pdf links you can directly call the addClass method on the variable **pdfs** because this is a jquery object and the class will be applied to all the links.

```js
var pdfs = jQuery("a[href$='.pdf']"); //Choosing .pdf links
pdfs.addClass("pdf"); // Adding the class
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Answer (score 0):

`addClass(className)` is a method of DOM element object. Must be called with element object. when we call `addClass()` without DOM object reference it look for local function, and thus throw the reference error.

```
var pdfs = jQuery("a[href$='.pdf']"); 
pdfs.each(function() {
  $(this).addClass( "foo" );
});
```

Comment: It's also available for jQuery collection objects, which makes jQuery so convenient. `pdfs.addClass("pdf");` does the job.

Comment: Yes, @connexo. But I explained about native addClass() method

Answer (score 0):

So... in whole:

```
$("a[href$='.pdf']").each(function () {
   $(this).addClass("pdf");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`.each` needs a function (`delegate`) for calling it for per item of `jQuery` result, but `func()` (in this case: `addClass(..)`) will call addClass function (that is not defined in current scope) and pass **result of calling it** to `each` function.

you can access to `addClass` function of per item, like this:

```
pdfs.each(function(index, pdf){
   $(pdf).addClass(...);
});
```

or for all:

```
pdfs.addClass(...);
```